# Solving the functional equation f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+y√f(x)

Tags: functional-equations

The question is to solve the functional equation $$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+y\sqrt{f(x)}$$ $\forall x,y \in \mathbb R$

I tried to put x=y=0,y=x and y=-x in the given functional equation.I ended up getting $$f(2x)=3f(x)+f(-x)$$ and $$f(x)+f(-x)=x\sqrt{f(x})$$ from where I am unable to proceed.Thanks.

Comment: At least we know that $f(x)\equiv 0$ is a solution:)

Comment: Another solution is $x^2/4$

Comment: @LeBtz I said $x^2$ divided by $4$ not just $x^2$

Comment: @kingW3 Yes, my bad. It still doesnt hold for $x=-1, y=1$

Comment: Since this question was closed even though the answers in the linked question aswell come to the solution $x^2/4$ (which is wrong), I posted my answer in the linked question again and deleted it here.